# group a a list of dictionaries in a dictionary by date, and get the highest value in each day

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have the following list of dictionaries:

```
[{'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
  'Total_Vaccinations': 42107850,
  'Total_Individuals': None,
  'LastValue': 0,
  'ObjectId': 13452,
  'Elderly': 1655476,
  'FirstDose': 23386741,
  'SecondDose': 18721109},
 {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
  'Total_Vaccinations': 42107619,
  'Total_Individuals': None,
  'LastValue': 0,
  'ObjectId': 13451,
  'Elderly': 1655474,
  'FirstDose': 23386687,
  'SecondDose': 18720932},
 {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
  'Total_Vaccinations': 42107429,
  'Total_Individuals': None,
  'LastValue': 0,
  'ObjectId': 13450,
  'Elderly': 1655473,
  'FirstDose': 23386644,
  'SecondDose': 18720785},
 {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
  'Total_Vaccinations': 42107125,
  'Total_Individuals': None,
  'LastValue': 0,
  'ObjectId': 13449,
  'Elderly': 1655468,
  'FirstDose': 23386571,
  'SecondDose': 18720554},
 {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
  'Total_Vaccinations': 42106807,
  'Total_Individuals': None,
  'LastValue': 0,
  'ObjectId': 13448,
  'Elderly': 1655464,
  'FirstDose': 23386503,
  'SecondDose': 18720304}
```

since there are multiple dictionaries for each day, I'd like to get the highest `Total_Vaccinations` value for each single day.

I was able to group dictionaries by day and I was also able to get highest value for a specific key, however, I couldn't do both at the same time.
Any suggestions? (I'm using Python)

Comment: It looks like all the data in the sample set has the same day (2021-09-30)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could have **multiple** dictionaries for the same day, I think that this simple approach would do the job:

```
res = {}
for i in list_dictionaries:
   res[i['Reportdt']] = max(i['Total_Vaccinations'], res.get(i['Reportdt'], 0))
```

Comment: that solved it! can you explain, what does .get do exactly? and how did it group the dates? –

Comment: @KhalidAlolayan I create an empty dictionary `res={}` to cache the highest value by date. In a dictionary, the function `get` allows you to specify a default value (in our case, 0) in case the key you use does not exist: `res.get(i['Reportdt'], 0)` will return 0 if `Reportdt` is not found in the dictionary. `max` returns the highest between the value you are processing in that iteration `i["Total_Vaccinations"]` and the current maximum stored in the dictionary for that date. The result of that evaluation is then stored in the dictionary `res` using the date `i["Reportdt"]` as key.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) or `sorted` to sort the list of dictionaries. For example, you can use the below to sort by date (most recent first) and then by total vaccinations (highest to lowest).

```py
from pprint import pprint

my_list = [{'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
            'Total_Vaccinations': 42107850,
            'Total_Individuals': None,
            'LastValue': 0,
            'ObjectId': 13452,
            'Elderly': 1655476,
            'FirstDose': 23386741,
            'SecondDose': 18721109},
           {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
            'Total_Vaccinations': 42107619,
            'Total_Individuals': None,
            'LastValue': 0,
            'ObjectId': 13451,
            'Elderly': 1655474,
            'FirstDose': 23386687,
            'SecondDose': 18720932},
           {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
            'Total_Vaccinations': 42107429,
            'Total_Individuals': None,
            'LastValue': 0,
            'ObjectId': 13450,
            'Elderly': 1655473,
            'FirstDose': 23386644,
            'SecondDose': 18720785},
           {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
            'Total_Vaccinations': 42107125,
            'Total_Individuals': None,
            'LastValue': 0,
            'ObjectId': 13449,
            'Elderly': 1655468,
            'FirstDose': 23386571,
            'SecondDose': 18720554},
           {'Reportdt': '2021-09-30',
            'Total_Vaccinations': 42106807,
            'Total_Individuals': None,
            'LastValue': 0,
            'ObjectId': 13448,
            'Elderly': 1655464,
            'FirstDose': 23386503,
            'SecondDose': 18720304}]

my_list.sort(key=lambda x: (x['Reportdt'], x['Total_Vaccinations']),
             # Reverse to sort by highest -> lowest
             reverse=True)

print(f'-- List:')
pprint(my_list)

day_with_highest_vac = my_list[0]
print('-- Day with highest vaccination:')
pprint(day_with_highest_vac)
```

Answer (score 0):

if `pandas` is ok for you then

```
df=pd.DataFrame(my_list_of_dicts)
print(df.sort_values(['Reportdt', 'Total_Vaccinations'], ascending=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

A `convtools`-based alternative (date parsing added):

```py
from datetime import datetime

from convtools import conversion as c

parse_dt = c.call_func(datetime.strptime, c.this(), "%Y-%m-%d").call_method(
    "date"
)
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("Reportdt"))
    .aggregate(
        {
            "report_dt": c.item("Reportdt").pipe(parse_dt),
            "total_vaccinations": c.ReduceFuncs.Max(
                c.item("Total_Vaccinations")
            ),
            "elderly": c.ReduceFuncs.Max(c.item("Elderly")),
        }
    )
    .gen_converter()
)
assert converter(input_data) == [
    {
        'report_dt': datetime.date(2021, 9, 30),
        'total_vaccinations': 42107850,
        'elderly': 1655476
    }
]
```